# Will Komputerbay 8GB (2x 4GB) DDR3 SODIMM (204 pin) 1333Mhz PC3 10600 8 GB (9-9-9-25) work for my Thinkpad T500

Tags: memory, compatibility, thinkpad

Can someone tell me if there is any reason that this ram will not work in my Thinkpad T500 
2055-2cu?

When I ordered the ram, I checked the specs and it looked like it was compatible, but after installing it I got the 1-3-3-1 BIOS beep. I switched back to my original chip, and luckily I hadn't damaged my mobo (as the computer booted fine).

So, could there be something I missed when I checked the specs, that could be causing the 
problem? (Does this particular model "2055-2cu" only support 2GB modules?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That system does support 4GB modules - I'd recommend the Kingston part # KTL-TP3B/4G  x2.  You could just have received a bad stick of memory; we see it all the time at our shop.  Return it if you can and get the Kingston part # I listed or first test one stick at a time - only one of the sticks is likely bad.

Comment: As I was saying, I had already tried both and neither worked.